# link wrap with li tag

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Is it possible to create link wrap with li tag?
am using cakephp2

```
$this->Html->link(
                 __('title'),array('controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => false)
                , array('class' => "", 'id' => "")
              );
```

Comment: I am sorry,its mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<li>
<?php 
echo $this->Html->link(
    __('title'),
    array(
        'controller' => 'controller',
        'action' => 'index', 
        'admin' => false
    ),
    array('class' => "", 'id' => "")
);
?>
</li>
```

don't make things more confusing than they need to be.

or if you really must use Cake use [HtmlHelper::tag](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3atag),

```
$this->Html->tag('li', $this->Html->link(..)); // <li><a href="..">..</a></li>
```

Comment: +1. Using `Html->tag` is appropriate if the code is inside a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what you posted is not a input box, it is a Link.
I'm assuming you are trying to wrap a Input inside a li tag.

A Quick Search in the CakePHP Book resulted in this approach:

(for cakePHP 2.0 or higher)

```
echo $this->Form->input('field', array(
    'before' => '--before--',
    'after' => '--after--',
    'between' => '--between---'
));
```

This Code Results in the following Html

```
<div class="input">
--before--
<label for="UserField">Field</label>
--between---
<input name="data[User][field]" type="text" value="" id="UserField" />
--after--
</div>
```

I think this is exactly what you were looking for.

In the future before Posting a Question anywhere, you should first check the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html)

Comment: Then that means that Ross answered your question, don't forget to approve the Answer!